# Is there a way to know when an app is deleted in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

my problem is this:

I have scheduled some UILocalNotifications on an iOS app, the problem is that if I delete the app without deleting the objects associated with the notifications (and consequently removing the notifications from the scheduledNotifications array) the notifications still fire.

Although I have not experienced them actually firing (they are set to repeat within a week's interval) I have evidence of this since I NSLog the scheduledNotifications array at application launch, which even after deleting the app and reinstalling it (with the entities of the data model gone), still shows some scheduled notifications.

I've searched the UIApplication and the UIApplicationDelegate reference in Apple's reference library but I found no method to know if the app is being deleted, if there is I would just write

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

in said method.

So, is there a way for knowing this?

Thank you in advance, your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: There is no method to check that the app was uninstalled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was bug in 4.0 that the local notification was repeated even if the user has deleted the app, but at least that bug was fixed by Apple in later release.

Comment: I am working with iOS 4.2, unless it is some kind of issue with the simulator.

Comment: Check it in device. If the problem exists then file a bug

Comment: The local notifications will show once the app is reinstalled. Seems like another bug.

Comment: @KingofBliss does the problem exists for push notifications also??? as the Device ID is registered and when the App is deleted the Device ID should be deleted but as there is no such method to check that the app was uninstalled so how do we delete the Device ID???

Comment: @ishhhh you cant find whether the app is deleted by the user.

Comment: @ishhhh whenevr the application is launched, register the deviceID to the server. If there is no call from the device for a month or more,then delete the device it. Also the local notification problem is not with ush notification.

Comment: @KingofBliss What about LocalNotifications? Is there a solution to prevent them from firing after the app is reinstalled? Or is it just a bug as Gomfucius says?

Comment: I`m working on iOS 6.0.1 and the issue is still there. At least when I install the app on the device via Xcode or TestFlight...