# Canceling Repeat UILocalNotification in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

i used this [Link](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/9/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html) to set Repeat UILocalNotification and my code run successfully but the problem is that even when i delete my Application , alerts are poping up is there is any way to cancel the repeat UILocalNotification pragmatically

this is the code which i am using to set repeat UILocalNotification after 1 minute

```
- (void)alertSelector:(NSString *)AlertTitle WithFiringTime:(NSDate *)date{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
    if (!localNotification) 
        return;
    [localNotification setFireDate:date];
    [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:date forKey:@"payload"];
    [localNotification setUserInfo:data];
    [localNotification setAlertBody:AlertTitle];
    [localNotification setAlertAction:@"View"];
    [localNotification setHasAction:YES];      
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;      
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

with the code below i cancel the UILocalNotification but it cancel all the UILocalNotification and i want to cancel only the UILocalNotification which is poping up after 1 minute , Repeat UILocalNotification

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Thankx in advance

Comment: I found my answer here is the [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999234/is-there-a-way-to-know-when-an-app-is-deleted-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `cancelAllLocalNotifications` you should retain the notification you wish to cancel at some point in the future and use the `cancelNotification:` method.

`cancelNotification:` lets you cancel specific notifications, but the fairly obvious caveat is you must keep the notification objects you wish to cancel hanging around!

Comment: thankx for your response @lxt but cancelNotifiaction: only cancel any particular notification for any particular date i want to cancel the repeat uilocalnotifications